# How MLE is used to train a n-gram model?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, n-gram, mle

I learned many documents about training a n-gram model using MLE, but as I noticed all the implementation is just to calculate the conditional probability by count the n-grams, my question is what is the relationship with MLE?

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, you would have to count all the n-grams in all texts in the world to compute their probabilities. Since this is highly unrealistic, MLE provides a way to estimate these n-gram probabilities by counting them in the given corpus.

For instance, if you need the bigram probability of a word *y* following a word *x*, you count the number of their occurrence as a pair, [image: C(xy)]. Then you have to normalize this count by dividing it by the sum of all bigrams starting with *x* (i.e: *x* being followed by every possible word), [image: sum of C(xz) over all z], so that the MLE estimate ultimately lies between 0 and 1.

Therefore, this bigram probability can be estimated by the following expression:

[image: P(y|x) = C(xy) / sum of C(xz) over all z]

Note that this expression can be further simplified because the sum of all bigram counts starting with *x* must add up to the unigram count of *x* itself:

[image: P(y|x) = C(xy) / (x)]